# Looking for a specyfic message in zipped pcap files

Tags: linux, unix, pcap, tcpdump, zcat

I have around 7200 compressed `.pcap` files. Each is compressed into a separate `.gz` file. I need to look for a specific string in packet data details. I would like to write a command to do that. At the moment all I have is:

```
zcat 20230212*.pcap.gz | tcpdump -qns 0 -X | grep "specyfic string"
```

where `20230212*.pcap.gz` is pattern for these 72000 files.

I know that problem is somewhere on tcpdump part. Sorry for my english.

**Update**

I tried

```
tcpdump -qns 0 -A -r filename.pcap | grep "string"
```

where `filename` is name of specyfic file, that contains string. It works, but I had to unzip this file. I cannot do it for all files. Also tried:

```
tcpdump -qns 0 -X -r filename.pcap | grep "string"
```

but this command cannot find `string`.

```
xargs zcat filename.pcap.gz | tcpdump -qns 0 -A -r | grep "string"
```

gives me: `tcpdump: option requires an argument -- 'r'`

Comment: when  you use a comand as you have "on the command-line", there are OS/Shell specific limiations on the number of "words" that can be on that command line AND the over-all number of characters on the cmd-line. You have clearly gone WAYYY over that limit. something like `xargs zcat * | tcpdump ....| grep ...` may work, or at least, that is the place to start. Make a test dir and copy 2 files to it. Run my command in that dir, the your question with error messages. Good luck.

Comment: And, I am trusting that the output of `tcpdump -qns 0 -X` will be "clean" so that `grep` can work. If its not, the you need to edit your question to show a sample line of output from `tcpdump` so we can help find a command to reformat (?) it so `grep` will work. Good luck!

Comment: @cinosz Please [edit] your question to add information, e.g. to show other commands you tried and the resulting output or error message.

Comment: Please update your question above with any new data/discoveries you make. Use 4 spaces at the front of each line so we get `code/data/output/errMsg` formatting. Good luck.

Comment: After using: 
`xargs zcat "filename" | tcpdump -qns 0 -X | grep "string`,

I receive
`tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode
listening on bond0, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 262144 bytes`

Comment: `filename` is specific filename, that definitely contains `string` in some packet data details.

Comment: You reply in comments is not understandable. **please** copy/paste that information into the bottom of the body of your question above and use 4 spaces at the front of each line.  And maybe you want to take `xargs zcat` out of the picture, Unzip the file and just run `tcpdump .... filename` (no .zip) ?  Try running it with the `verbose` flags, does the `grep` now work? Problem solved! Good luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> `tcpdump: option requires an argument -- 'r'`

The `-r` flag needs to be given an argument to indicate what to read.

An argument of `-` means "read the standard input", which is what you want here, as you're piping the result of `zcat` to it.

So you want

```
zcat filename.pcap.gz | tcpdump -qns 0 -A -r - | grep "string"
```

You *don't* want `xargs`, because, with

```
xargs zcat filename.pcap.gz | tcpdump -qns 0 -A -r - | grep "string"
```

it will:

- read file names from the standard input of the first command - meaning that, if you run that exact command from the command line, it will read file names from the *terminal*, so *you* would have to type a bunch of file names, followed by control-D to mark the end of the list of file names;
- collect the file names into bunches;
- run `zcat filename.pcap.gz {bunch of file names}` - meaning that it will decompresss first filename.pcap.gz, followed by all of the files in that bunch, and write the decompressed contents of all those files as a *single* stream of raw bytes;
- read more file names and do that again until it runs out of file names;

which means that what tcpdump will see will look like a bunch of pcap-format files stuck together ("concatenated") into one.  That will *NOT* look like a single pcap-format file to tcpdump; instead, it will look like the first pcap file, followed by a lot of stuff that will not look like valid pcap file contents, so tcpdump will probably print an error and give up.

(And other programs that read pcap-format files, such as tshark, will do the exact same thing.  There's no magic flag or tool to fix that.)

What you should do, instead, is have a small shell script, such as

```
#! /bin/sh
echo "Processing $1:"
zcat "$1" | tcpdump -qns 0 -A -r - | grep "$2"
```

and, to look for a given string in one .pcap.gz file, do

```
{path to script} {file name} "string"
```

where {path to script} is the path name of the script and {file name} is the pathname of the file.

To scan *all* the files, do

```
for file in 20230212*.pcap.gz
do
    {path to script} "$file" "string"
done >/tmp/output
```

That is a loop that loops over all files that match 20230212*.pcap.gz and, for each of them, runs the script on the file, looking for the string, and sends the output of that entire loop to the file /tmp/output.

Note that /tmp/output will contain one line for *every* file, giving the name of the file.  If you don't care *which* capture files contain the string, you can remove the

```
echo "Processing $1:"
```

line from the script.  If you *do* care which capture files contain the string, but you don't care what the exact text that matches is, you can have the script be

```
#! /bin/sh
echo "Processing $1:"
if zcat "$1" | tcpdump -qns 0 -A -r - | grep -q "$2"
then
    echo "$1 contains \"$2\""
fi
```

which tests whether the `grep` command found the string and, if it did, prints a message. The `-q` flag causes `grep` not to write the matching text out, so the file doesn't have that extra information in it.

> After using:  `xargs zcat "filename" | tcpdump -qns 0 -X | grep "string`, I receive `tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode listening on bond0, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 262144 bytes`

That's because you didn't provide a `-r` argument to tcpdump, which means that will capture network traffic from a network interface; because you also didn't specify a `-i` argument, which would specify an interface from which to capture, it will pick the first interface that shows up in the list it gets from the system, which happened to be bond0 on your system.

You need to specify `-r` to get tcpdump to read from a capture file.

> but this command cannot find string.

That command uses `-X`, not `-A`, so it dumped out packet data in a format like this:

```
    0x0020:  5010 1920 a97a 0000 4854 5450 2f31 2e31  P....z..HTTP/1.1
    0x0030:  2032 3030 204f 4b0d 0a44 6174 653a 2046  .200.OK..Date:.F
    0x0040:  7269 2c20 3236 2041 7567 2032 3030 3520  ri,.26.Aug.2005.
```

There's no guarantee that the string will all fit on one line.